# Why bootstrap-tokenfield is not styled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am using bootstrap-tokenfield like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('tokenfield/jquery-migrate.js') }}"></script>
<link href="{{ asset('tokenfield/bootstrap-tokenfield.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="{{ asset('tokenfield/bootstrap-tokenfield.js') }}"></script>
```

But the problem is that my dropdown menu is not styled. It looks like normal html list.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="tokenfield" value="" />
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
     autocomplete: {
       source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
       delay: 100
     },
     showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Are there errors shown in the console?

Comment: nope, everything looks ok

Comment: can you try removing the class `.typeahead` in your input and see if anything happens?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Do you have bootstrap installed? If not you can try to add this custom css. https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/issues/156

Comment: The method you're using for Tokenfield requires jQuery UI - you're including the JavaScript, but are you including the jQuery UI stylesheets?

Comment: of course i do it